# Python regular expression for a sentence does not want to match

Tags: python, regex

Can anyone explain why this re (in Python):

```
pattern = re.compile(r"""
^
([[a-zA-Zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]+\s{1}]+)
([a-zA-Zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]+)   # Last word.
\.{1}                                                                                 
$
""", re.VERBOSE + re.UNICODE)

if re.match(pattern, line):
```

does not match "A sentence."

I would actually like to return the entire sentence (including the period) as a returned group (), but have been failing miserably.

Comment: is that comment actually in your regex or did you put it there for the question?

Comment: It's a verbose regex that allows comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe you meant to do this:

```
(([a-zA-Zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]+\s{1})+)
 ^                                             ^
```

I don't think the nested square brackets you had do what you think they do.

Comment: But that wouldn't allow me to get the entire sentence as a returned group and also isn't there a limit of 9 on the number of returned groups?

Comment: No, there's not a limit of nine, on my version of python, there's a limit of 100, but I think that's implementation specific. And the square brackets certainly don't do grouping. You're just defining a character class of the characters: `[a-zA-Zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ`, 1 or more times, followed by exactly 1 whitespace char, followed by 1 or more literal `]`s. Check out http://regex101.com/ , it's an awesome tool for learning/debugging regexes.

Comment: @Superdooperhero: you can't get a variable number of groups.  Your regex will only have as many groups as it has pairs of parens.

Comment: If I replace the [] with a () as you suggest, my (larger) program seems to go into an infinite loop; whereas previously it returned immediately. Also if I just use \w it works.

Comment: Actually might not be an infinite loop, might just be 50000000 times slower.

Comment: Just thinking about it a bit more, why not just use: `([a-zA-Zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ\s]+)`? Granted it will allow multiple whitespace characters in a row, but it does basically the same thing, and real data may well have duplicate whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"""
^
([a-zA-Zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]+\s{1})+
([a-zA-Zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]+)   # Last word.
\.{1}
$
""", re.VERBOSE + re.UNICODE)

line = "A sentence."

match = re.match(pattern, line)

>>> print "'%s'" % match.group(0)
'A sentence.'
>>> print "'%s'" % match.group(1)
'A '
>>> print "'%s'" % match.group(2)
'sentence'
```

To return the entire match (`line` in this case), use `match.group(0)`.

Because the first match group can match multiple times (once for each word except the last one), you can only access the next to last word using `match.group(1)`.

Btw, the `{1}` notation is not necessary in this case, matching once and only once is the default behavior, so this bit can be removed.

The extra set of square brackets definitely weren't helping you :)

Comment: Sadly this does not work when I use it as part of a larger regex. It then only returns the last word of any words in the first ()

Comment: That's the way regular expression groups work. A group that matches several times will only give access to the last match. What you can do however is to match the whole line, retrieve it with match.group(0), and then iterate over that line with a smaller regex to get each word, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the following actually works and includes all the extended ascii characters I wanted

```
^
([\w+\s{1}]+\w{1}\.{1})
$
```